# Work around for array in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass a string array (String separated by comma) to the stored procedure.. My requirement is to iterate, read & finally insert the values from String array..

I tried this like below,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_test(IN ArrayString VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
SET ArrayIndex = 0;

loop: LOOP    
  IF (ArrayIndex < ArrayString.length) THEN
    INSERT INTO temp SELECT parseString(ArrayString,ArrayIndex);     
  ELSE 
    LEAVE loop;  
  END IF; 
SET ArrayIndex = ArrayIndex + 1;
END LOOP loop;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

For example:
Input :

```
SET ArrayString = 'one,two,three,four';
```

`ArrayString.length` should return value 4 & loop should be iterate for 4 times

1st iteration:

```
ArrayIndex = 0;
parseString(ArrayString,ArrayIndex)
```

should return value 'one' & insert

2nd iteration:

```
ArrayIndex = 1;
parseString(ArrayString,ArrayIndex)
```

should return value 'two' & insert

3rd iteration:

```
ArrayIndex = 3;
parseString(ArrayString,ArrayIndex)
```

should return value 'three' & insert

4rd iteration:

```
ArrayIndex = 4;
parseString(ArrayString,ArrayIndex)
```

should return value 'four' & insert

**How to write code for ArrayString.length & parseString(ArrayString,ArrayIndex) ?**

Please Help...

Comment: Not that there's anything particularly wrong with it, but why don't you do this in application code?

Comment: How to write code for ArrayString.length & parseString(ArrayString,ArrayIndex) ?